# Is there a way to fine tune Autofac MVC3 Action Injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, autofac

So I got Action Injection with Autofac implemented in large MVC solution, or so I thought.

Turned out there were cases were it did not work properly.

In one of the views we were posting back manually some extra information, and model binder was able to match it up properly, like here:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string[] textInfo, bool[] boolInfo, SomeViewModel viewModel)
```

However as soon as I enabled action injection:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).InjectActionInvoker();
```

The first two parameters, are being received as empty arrays.

My hypothesis would be, that autofac figures out, those were not provided, and provides default value for those. Is there any way to work around this behavior? With some parameter-level attribute perhaps?

Comment: Which Autofac version are you using? Because it should work in version 3.0 and above...

Comment: 2.5.2.830, we did not upgrade because we are using autofac ASP.NET MVC 3 integration and it was never upgraded to autofac 3. I will try autofac 3 though, if it works there, it may be good reason to upgrade.